# For Ext.tree.Panel nodes, arrow button is not displayed, even though useArrow property is used

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1, extjs4.2

For `Ext.tree.Panel` nodes, arrow button is not displayed, even though useArrow property is used. While doing moveover the left of the nodes, pointer is displaying, but the visibility of arrow is false.

How can I solve this issue ??

Giving below the code, I used.

```
 Ext.create('Ext.tree.Panel', {
    useArrows: true,
    autoScroll: false,
    animate: true,
    enableDD: false,
    title: 'Configuration',
    width: 200,
    height: 150,
    rootVisible: false,
    store: [{
        root: {
            expanded: true,
            children: [{
                text: "Configure Application",
                expanded: true,
                children: [{
                    text: "Manage Application",
                    leaf: true
                }, {
                    text: "Scenario",
                    leaf: true
                }]
            }, {
                text: "User Configuration",
                expanded: true,
                children: [{
                    text: "Manage User",
                    leaf: true
                }, {
                    text: "User rights",
                    leaf: true
                }]
            }, {
                text: "Test Configuration",
                leaf: true,
                children: [{
                    text: "Manage User",
                    leaf: true
                }, {
                    text: "User rights",
                    leaf: true
                }]
            }]
        }
    }]
});
```

Attaching the screenshot of the UI tree.

[image]]

I am using extjs-4.2.2

Comment: What debugging have you done?

Comment: Sorry if I made any silly mistakes. Actually, I am new to Extjs, normally use to do browser level debugging(F12). I this scenario, there was no error

Comment: Are you using Sencha Cmd, and this is your first TreeGrid in the project? Then recompile the project, and the CSS should be updated. The uncompiled version of your project still relies on the compiled version of your stylesheet, because browsers normally cannot read uncompiled SCSS code. If you have no TreeGrid in the code, TreeGrid SCSS isn't compiled into the CSS, so with your first TreeGrid, it is missing.

Comment: @Alexander I am using maven. I build the complete project. Can please suggest me how to check weather css is available or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed your store definition and now it shows arrows as expected if useArrows property is set to true in config json.

You can try that in sencha fiddle.

```
var root = {
    expanded: true,
    children: [{
        text: "Configure Application",
        expanded: true,
        children: [{
            text: "Manage Application",
            leaf: true
        }, {
            text: "Scenario",
            leaf: true
        }]
    }, {
        text: "User Configuration",
        expanded: true,
        children: [{
            text: "Manage User",
            leaf: true
        }, {
            text: "User rights",
            leaf: true
        }]
    }, {
        text: "Test Configuration",
        leaf: true,
        children: [{
            text: "Manage User",
            leaf: true
        }, {
            text: "User rights",
            leaf: true
        }]
    }]
};

Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch: function() {
        Ext.create('Ext.tree.Panel', {
            useArrows: true,
            autoScroll: false,
            animate: true,
            enableDD: false,
            title: 'Configuration',
            width: 400,
            height: 400,
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            rootVisible: false,
            store: Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore', {
                root: root
            })
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: I have tried the same before and even now again, but still it's not working. Is it because of the Extjs version(extjs-4.2.2) I am using??

Comment: It works for me in Sencha fiddle with ExtJs 4.2.1 version.

Comment: It worked for me, some library path was wrong, but there was no error showing in the browser, like "404 Error"

Comment: @BijoyBahuleyan i am facing same error for similar impl. I am using Ext JS 5.1.0.107. I have useArrows set to true. But the arrows are not appearing. Any guidance on how to resolve this? What library path was wrong?